# Yii2 Kartik GridView SqlDataProvider toggleData not working

Tags: gridview, yii2

I'm using Yii2 with Kartik GridView with a SqlDataProvider and am trying to get the toggleData button to work. What I expect is that when clicked it will show all records, however it only shows the first page and removes the pagination buttons.
I haven't seen any examples of using SqlDataProvider which is why I'm a little concerned it's not working.

This is my simplified section of the controller:

```
$query = Entryrecord::find();
$count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' . $query->createCommand()->getRawSql() . ') as count_alias')->queryScalar();
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => $query->createCommand()->getRawSql(), 
    'totalCount' => $count,
    'pagination' => [
              'pageSize' => 10,
        ], 
]);
return $dataProvider;
```

In the View

```
$gridColumns = [
      'id',
      'created_date'
  ];

  echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'panel' => [
        'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
        'heading' => 'Records',
    ],
    'pjax' => true,
    'pjaxSettings' => ['options' => ['id' => 'kv-pjax-container']],
    // your toolbar can include the additional full export menu
    'toolbar' => [
        '{toggleData}',
        '{export}',
    ],
  ]);
```

For some reason it won't show the full list of results.

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Just in case, are there more than 10 records? If not, then it's logical to think it doesn't show pagination buttons.

Comment: Yes there are 747 records being returned, but only 10 per page.

Comment: Hmm, since I have never used this before, I'm not sure about the answer... unless I attempt this myself (maybe tomorrow). What if you increase the page size from 10 to, let's say, 30? Do you get all 30 records?

Comment: Yes - I get whatever I set the pagesize to. I have a feeling it is related to the SqlDataProvider, as if I use ActiveDataProvider it works. But my results include duplicate primary keys as rows returned have a single piece of data that is different for each row, but attached to the same primary key. With the ActiveDataProvider it filters those duplicates out (by design) so a SqlDataProvider needs to be used.

Comment: This happened with me when I updated the $dataProvider->models before rendering it. Make sure you didn't update $dataProvider->models.